# Dwm - pertag patch - save state between restarts

Tags: patch, dwm, tiling-wm

I'm using [Pertag patch](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/dwm-6.1-pertag.diff)

As a Gentoo user I apply dwm patches using Portage. Basically there's a directory where user can put a patch for sourcecode and Portage will apply it during the compilation process (if patching procedure goes wrong whole compilation will fail)

So basically I used just these commands:

```
cp ~/pertag.patch /etc/portage/patches/x11-wm/dwm
emerge -av dwm
```

Anyway Pertag patch seem to work fine - I can set different layouts for different tags etc, but when I restart dwm, all these changes are gone and I need to set it up again.

Is there a way (maybe different patch?) to save these changes, so when I start dwm again, tag 2 still has for example monocle layout, tag 3 floating layout, and there's no statusbar on tag 4?

Comment: What patch? Where did you get it? How did you apply it? A patch is normally applied to source code which is then recompiled, what exactly are you doing?

Comment: I'm talking about "Pertag" patch from suckless.org It works fine but applied changes like tag's layout are gone after dwm's restart

Comment: Yes, I guessed as much from your question, but what is this patch? Where did you get it and, most importantly, how exactly did you apply it?

Comment: I get it directly from suckless.org and applied on source via "patch < pertag.diff". Like I said it is working fine. I can set different layouts for different tags etc - but these changes are gone after dwm restart. My question is: is there a way for this changes to be restored when dwm is restarted

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the link where you found this patch and the exact commands you ran. If you have indeed recompilied `dwm`, the changes should be permanent unless you are running the unpatched version when you restart. We can't help though unless you _show what you've done_ so we can understand what you're doing and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dwm is an acronym for *dynamic* window manager: the central principle of dwm is that the tags are supposed to be dynamic, not fixed. See [why tags don't remember their layout](http://web.archive.org/web/20120120161931/http://lubutu.com/rant/dwm-faq). The [pertag patch](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/pertag) breaks this paradigm.

If you want to be able to have your window manager use static *workspaces*, you are better off using [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) or [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) (both inspired by dwm).

However, if you really are intent on patching out dwm's core and defining feature, there are some patches floating about that will do this, like Jokerboy's [remember tags](http://hg.punctweb.ro/dwm/src/tip/14-dwm-6.0-remember-tags.diff) patch, which should be used in conjunction with his [pertag patch](http://hg.punctweb.ro/dwm/src/tip/01-dwm-6.0-pertag2.diff).

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping that you'll answer. Your YT video about dwm was the main reason I wanted to try it :)

Comment: @dqq Happy to help. Use dwm for a while without pertag and you'll appreciate the power of tags :)